# navigator.pop() instead of closing a alertDialog closes the home page allowing the user to bypass email verification

Tags: flutter

Whenever I try and run the function signUserUp I end up with a CircularProgressIndicator() looping, allowing the user to click out and go into the homePage without email verification which I of course don't want. There's no code allowing the user to navigate there so i'm assuming it has something to do with how the screens stack. However Navigator.pop() doesn't get rid of the CircularProgressIndicator() and instead closes the registerPage. If somebody else can see anything here that might interefere with the code I would be happy to see what it is. Do note: The Signing up process most likely doesn't have anything to do with the error.

```
Future<void> signUserUp() async {
    showDialog(
     context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );

    try {
      // Check if passwords match
      if (passwordController.text != confirmPasswordController.text) {
        Navigator.pop(context);
        showErrorMessage("Passwords do not match");
        return;
      } else {
        UserCredential userCredential =
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text,
          password: passwordController.text,
        );

        // Send verification email
        await userCredential.user!.sendEmailVerification();

        // Stop the loading indicator
        Navigator.pop(context);

        // Show Request message using showErrormessage
        showErrorMessage(
            'Registration successful!\nPlease verify your email to complete the registration.',
          );

      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // Stop the loading indicator
      Navigator.pop(context);

      // Show error message
      showErrorMessage(e.code);
    }
  }

  void showErrorMessage(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            message,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

The code for the Button That runs the code is:

```
MyButton(
  text: "Sign Up",
 onTap: () async {
  await signUserUp();
    },},
```

I was excepting to see a CircularProgressIndicator, have that popped (didn't happen), have the user be signed up (which happened), have an email verification be sent to them (which happened), then have a alertDialog (done by the function showErrorMessage) but it didn't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're calling `Navigator.pop(context)`, it uses the `context` of your stateful widget by default. That's why it's closing the screen you're on instead of the dialog. To fix this, all you have to do is use the `context` of the dialog builder when calling `Navigator.pop(context)`

```dart
Future<void> signUserUp() async {
    BuildContext dialogContext = context; //context here is taken from your stateful widget
    showDialog(
     context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        dialogContext = context; //context here is taken from your dialog builder
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );

    try {
      // Check if passwords match
      if (passwordController.text != confirmPasswordController.text) {
        Navigator.pop(dialogContext);
        showErrorMessage("Passwords do not match");
        return;
      } else {
        UserCredential userCredential =
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text,
          password: passwordController.text,
        );

        // Send verification email
        await userCredential.user!.sendEmailVerification();

        // Stop the loading indicator
        Navigator.pop(dialogContext);

        // Show Request message using showErrormessage
        showErrorMessage(
            'Registration successful!\nPlease verify your email to complete the registration.',
          );

      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      // Stop the loading indicator
      Navigator.pop(dialogContext);

      // Show error message
      showErrorMessage(e.code);
    }
  }

  void showErrorMessage(String message) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text(
            message,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: For some reason now it instead destroys both the loading indicator AND the screen and doesn't show the pop-up at all. But for some reason whenever there's an error it can stop the loading indicator just fine just when you get signed up for some reason.